# Why do :hover delay?

Tags: iphone, css, hover, mousehover

I've always wondered about the `:hover` clause when tapping elements, they always seem to delay, for example, an element that will have a red background the `:hover`, however it takes about a second to change the background.

Another thing why this made me wondered, mobile sites such as Facebook `m.facebook.com`, when tapping on elements, they seem to response instantly when background changes (like tapping on a notification).

How do I make this effect the same when using `:hover`?

Okay... due to no-one gets what I mean. A typical page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale = 1.0; minimum-scale = 1.0; user-scalable = 0;" />
<style type="text/css">

.row {
    padding: 20px;  
}

.row a:hover .row {
    background-color: red;
}

</style>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <a href="#">Typical link</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="#">Typical link</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="#">Typical link</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you viewed this on an iPhone, when tapping on a link, the background of `.row` takes just a second to change the background to red.

I'm using an iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.3.3 - surely that doesn't affect anything because it's been like that since iOS 3.x.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Please at least show your code. Your browser and its version. Voting it down for lack of additional information.

Comment: A large red panel will appear to stay that color longer if you stare at it. It's hard for your eyes to immediately notice the color change on warm colors like red.

Comment: Updated my post.

@Justin Satyr - that's the most funniest comment I've seen, it doesn't appear until AFTER you tap the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a touchscreen device the events are a bit different - without a cursor, hover is fairly meaningless.

If the default behaviour doesn't provide the response you want, you will need to use javascript to add a hover/selected class based on touch events. On iOS the touchend event fires several hundred milliseconds before the click event, and something similar likely applies to the hover behaviour.

Comment: You can look at the [FastClick](http://assanka.net/content/tech/2011/08/26/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/) code to see how we solve this problem for click events.